# Get the second last ID by date, based on the current ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table something like:

| CNPJ | TARGET_CNPJ | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05775774000108 | 01638542000157 | 2012-03-12 |
| 05775774000108 | 62418140000131 | 2014-03-12 |
| 05775774000108 | 59281253000123 |  |
| 10951930000184 | 02201501000161 | 2010-04-26 |
| 10951930000184 | 62285390000140 | 2010-05-25 |
| 10951930000184 | 61809182000130 |  |

What i'm trying to achieve is getting the last TARGET_CNPJ, Based on the END_DATE (Like get the last record before the current):

| CNPJ | TARGET_CNPJ | END_DATE | LAST_CNPJ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05775774000108 | 01638542000157 | 2012-03-12 | No Previous TARGET_CNPJ |
| 05775774000108 | 62418140000131 | 2014-03-12 | 01638542000157 |
| 05775774000108 | 59281253000123 |  | 62418140000131 |
| 10951930000184 | 02201501000161 | 2010-04-26 | No Previous TARGET_CNPJ |
| 10951930000184 | 62285390000140 | 2010-05-25 | 02201501000161 |
| 10951930000184 | 61809182000130 |  | 61809182000130 |

Is it possible to achive it via MySQL Query?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use `LAG` function: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/

Comment: UNTESTED: `select CNPJ, Target_CNPJ, End_Date, Lag(TargetCNPJ) over (partition by CNPJ order by end date desc)` FROM tblName  note: you'll not get "no previous target..." you'll just get NULL.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, in that case, the entries that has 'null' dates are not responding correctly. I'm trying to fill this fields with the curdate() (wich corresponds to reality), but I can't make the 'order by' entry of lag function trough this created column.

Trying to solve it by searching on similar topics on stackoverflow. If you (or anyone) has an suggestions, I would apreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    CNPJ,
    TARGET_CNPJ,
    END_DATE,
    LAG(TARGET_CNPJ) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(END_DATE, NOW())) LAST_CNPJ
FROM MyTable
```